# Fragment splash screen not showing in main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app with a tabbed menu (`ViewPager`) and I'm trying to add a splash screen to it.

The tabs are working as they should, but I can't seem to make `SplashFragment` run before the tabs are shown (until a user is authenticated, but that's a different story)

My question is **what is wrong with the code below that could cause the fragment not to show?**

Some info:
There is only 1 `FragmentActivity` (MainActivity.java/activity_main.xml), which has a `ViewPager` in it.

Here's my `activity_main.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/frag_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
```

Here's my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    //uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /***********************************/
    /****** SETTING FRAGMENT HERE ******/
    /***********************************/
    FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction xact = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
    if (null == fragMgr.findFragmentByTag("splashScreen")) {
        xact.add(R.id.frag_container, new SplashFragment(), "splashScreen").commit();
    }

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,SelectionFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,SplashFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,SelectionFragment.class.getName()));

    mAdapter = new fragAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.size(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab " + (i+1)).setTabListener(tabListener));
    }

    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

Comment: Why not just have another activity for your splashscreen? http://blog.blundell-apps.com/tut-splashscreen-with-progress-bar/

Comment: Thanks. But I will still need to eventually load other things... or should I just use activities? I'm new and I don't know when it's good to use fragments or activities so.... I could create another `Fragment Starter` activity, and pass it fragments to load every time I need to load a fragment not within the `ViewPager`. Is it good practice though?

Comment: You want your Activity to do one thing. So yes an AppStartActivity would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a layout problem. Your `ViewPager` is `layout_height="match_parent"`, so when it gets measured, it gets the full screen height. Then, when the `FrameLayout` gets measured, there's no space left for it, so it gets 0px height. Either hide the `ViewPager` while you're showing the splash screen (`GONE`, not `INVISIBLE`) or make it `layout_height="wrap_content"` and use weights to figure out how big they should be (or don't use a `LinearLayout`).